# How to get the particular dictionary values in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So far i am using this coding in the mvc 2 in controller page.
Here `employeeInfoList = EmployeeInfoProxy.GetAllEmployeeInfo(TenantId);`

  employeeInfoList in that i geting the values of the particular  'tenantid' after that i wnat to assign it in the viewdata for the particular view...

so that is used valus.tolist() i am getting generic error.......

```
  public ActionResult Edit(string TenantId) 
{ 
  try 
  { 
      Dictionary<string, EmployeeInfo> employeeInfoList = new Dictionary<string, EmployeeInfo>(); 
    employeeInfoList = EmployeeInfoProxy.GetAllEmployeeInfo(TenantId); 
    if (employeeInfoList != null) 
    { 
      EmployeeInfo employee = employeeInfoList.Values.ToList(); //here i want to bind the values to the employeeinfo but genric error is cuming 
      ViewData["Department"] = employee.Department; 
      ViewData["Designation"] = employee.Designation; 
      ViewData["Address1"] = employee.Address1; 
    } 

  } 
  catch (Exception ex) 
  { 
  } 
  return View(); 
}
```

Comment: can u explain it further.. what does GetAllEmployeeInfo(TenantId) return.And what is the error u get..?

Comment: EmployeeInfoProxy.GetAllEmployeeInfo(TenantId);

Comment: it returns the values of the particular tenantid

Comment: in employeeInfoList it gets the all the values of the tenantid like address,department,designation.after that i want to assign it in the viewdata this is my issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
EmployeeInfo employee = employeeInfoList.Values.ToList();
```

the ToList() method returns a List object, but you are trying to assign it to a single employeeInfo object.

```
Dictionary<string, EmployeeInfo> employeeInfoList = new Dictionary<string, EmployeeInfo>(); 
    employeeInfoList = EmployeeInfoProxy.GetAllEmployeeInfo(TenantId); 

    if (employeeInfoList != null) 
    { // assuming you really only want the first one.  What if GetAllEmployeeInfo() returns more than one employee???
      EmployeeInfo employee = employeeInfoList.Values.FirstOrDefault(); 
      ViewData["Department"] = employee.Department; 
      ViewData["Designation"] = employee.Designation; 
      ViewData["Address1"] = employee.Address1; 
    }
```

Comment: "employeeInfoList " in that i am getting count 3

Comment: I edited the code to return the first of the values collection, which should fix the error you were getting. 
However, this doesn't solve the logical problem that the code looks like it's returning 3 employees, and you still have to decide which one of them to display on this view.  FirstOrDefault() may not be what you want.  you might want to display a list of employees? if so, I would just do something like this: ViewData["Employees"] = employeeInfoList.Values; and iterate through that list in your view.

Comment: i am having 3 rows in gridview. Whenever i  click the EDIT Button in the particular row, the particular row details should be binded in the EDIT.aspx page.but coding u sent is returning only for first row.if i click the thrid row also first row values are displayed

Comment: for reference i sending my view screen

Comment: Then you need to add some logic that takes the ID of the user you clicked on, and get that user from the list of returned users, or something like that.  But that logic is up to you.  You need to control what parameters are sent to the server when you click on the edit button, and use that information to find the correct user to display.

But I think that your original question was answered, wasn't it? Or are you still getting an error?

Comment: Also, thought I'd point out that the first line of code in your sample isn't really necessary - you create a new Dictionary object, which is immediatly thrown away when you assign the variable the new object returned from GetAllEmploeeInfo.

personally I would declare and assign the employeeInfoList variable all in the same statement.

    var employeeInfoList = EmployeeInfoProxy.GetAllEmployeeInfo(TenantId);

or 

    Dictionary<string, EmployeeInfo> employeeInfoList = EmployeeInfoProxy.GetAllEmployeeInfo(TenantId);

if you don't like using var...

Comment: i am not getting error but if click the thrid record to shows only first record did u see my view page

Comment: Dictionary<string, EmployeeInfo> employeeInfoList = EmployeeInfoProxy.GetAllEmployeeInfo(TenantId);
i used this coding "employeeInfoList" i getting three records

Comment: if click the third record first record only its shows pls help

Comment: Yes, I did, but as I said before then you need to pick whichever one is the correct record.  Don't use FirstOrDefault(). Use some other logic to find the correct record. That is your logic to decide. There is no way anyone else can know which of the three users is the right one.

Comment: Actually it is suspicious that the method you are using to retreive the employee is actually returning 3 employees with that ID. normally when the user clicks the edit button, the id of that particular row would be sent to the controller, and you would use some method to get that one employee back from the database.  Are you certain you're using the right method to retrieve the records you're interested in, or are sending an appropriate ID?  If your original question is answered, you might consider marking one of our answers as your choice :)

Comment: actually i am using cellosaas application do u have any idea about that

Comment: Karthik, you tagged your own answer as the accepted answer, which doesn't seem right after the help I gave you. Please reconsider.

Comment: Sorry I have Done UnKnownligly

Answer (score 2):

You are casting list to one obj, it should be same type.
If it is returning dictionary or any list type then you should iterate with it or get the DefaultOrSingle() in that list.
See if this works,

```
var empinfo =EmployeeInfoProxy.GetAllEmployeeInfo(TenantId).FisrstorDefault(); 
if (empinfo !=null) 
{ 
  EmployeeInfo employee = employeeInfoList.FisrstorDefault(); 
  ViewData["Department"] = employee.Department; 
  ViewData["Designation"] = employee.Designation; 
  ViewData["Address1"] = employee.Address1; 
}
```

Comment: i am getting error in the second line "no overload for method 'Add'takes 1 aruguments

Comment: modified answer check now. As i said your mismatching with types.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="CelloSaaS.View.CelloViewPage" %>


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "EmployeeInfo"))
   {%>
<div class="content-admin">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>
            <asp:Literal ID="addPackage" runat="server" Text="Employee" /></h1>
        <div class="imageAlign">
            <input type="image" src="<%= this.ResolveClientUrl("../../App_Themes/CelloSkin/btn-save.gif")%>"
                alt="Add Employee Details" />
            <a href="..EmployeeInfo/EmployeeInfoList">
                <img src="<%= this.ResolveClientUrl("../../App_Themes/CelloSkin/ico-previous.png")%>"
                    alt="Back To Employee List" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table-main">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" class="details">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th colspan="4">
                                            <asp:Literal ID="litPackageDetails" runat="server" Text="EmployeeDetails" />
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="row4">
                                        <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text="EmployeeName">
                                        </asp:Literal>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="row5">
                                        <%= Html.TextBox("Name", (string)ViewData["Name"])%>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="row4">
                                        <asp:Literal ID="DepartmentName" runat="server" Text="DepartmentName">
                                        </asp:Literal>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="row5">
                                        <%= Html.TextBox("Department", (string)ViewData["Department"])%>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="row4">
                                        <asp:Literal ID="Literal2" runat="server" Text="Designation">
                                        </asp:Literal>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="row5">
                                        <%= Html.TextBox("Designation", (string)ViewData["Designation"])%>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="row4">
                                        <asp:Literal ID="Literal3" runat="server" Text="Salary">
                                        </asp:Literal>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="row5">
                                        <%= Html.TextBox("Salary", (string)ViewData["Salary"])%>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="row4">
                                        <asp:Literal ID="Address1" runat="server" Text="Address1"></asp:Literal>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="row5">
                                        <%= Html.TextArea("Address", (string)ViewData["Address"])%>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="row4">
                                        <asp:Literal ID="Literal4" runat="server" Text="Address2"></asp:Literal>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="row5">
                                        <%= Html.TextArea("Address1", (string)ViewData["Address1"])%>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<% } %>
```